# How to obtain elastic net regression coefficients from model created with the caret package train function

Tags: r-caret

I am wondering how can I obtain the final model regression coefficients for an elastic net model fitted using the train function from the caret package.

I tried using

```
coef(enetModelObj$finalModel)
```

but this gets me Null.
Thanks for your help.
LG

Comment: You need to provide more information than that. What function from which package did you use to build the model?

Comment: @LG77 did you ever get an answer?

Comment: Other than calling `predict()` with `type="coefficients"`.